# zurb foundation 5 icon bar Text Misaligned

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I have a weird issue with the text under the icon bar not being centered under the icons.

code example

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 columns">
    <div class="icon-bar five-up small">
      <a class="item" a href="/index.html">
        <i class="fi-home"></i>
        <div>
          <label>Home</label>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a class="item" a href="/cart.html">
        <i class="fi-shopping-cart"></i>
        <div>
          <label>Cart</label>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a class="item" a href="/pages/about-us">
        <i class="fi-info"></i>
        <div>
          <label>About</label>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a class="item" a href="/pages/contact-us">
        <i class="fi-mail"></i>
        <div>
          <label>Contact</label>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a class="item" a href="/account/login">
        <i class="fi-torso"></i>
        <div>
          <label>Account</label>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried to center the labels with no luck. Has anyone had any issue with this before. Can't post a screenshot since it's a new account. but the contact label and account label seem to start on the left of the icon and go right instead of the start of the actual icon box.

Comment: Only Has an issue on Moblie **

Comment: You should provide a live example. Use JSFiddle.

Comment: Can you provide a Fiddle?

Comment: what is the problems? [JSFiddles](http://jsfiddle.net/sLk0jf4L/45/)

Comment: the problems is the words "cart" / "home" is too high of the space that you allow.. you could fix it To remove the text and just keep Icon. Most of website do that for this reason. Or you need to create some Media Query and trying to play with "left property" for each div

Comment: not sure i can use js fiddle since it uses foundations css and icons packs etc.

Comment: looks fine here https://jsfiddle.net/76h4y08d/

Answer (score 0):

Ok your problems is about CSS in foundation. the property "padding" here:

```
.icon-bar > * {
   font-size: 1rem;
   padding: 1.25rem;
}
```

To fix that, you need to add a media query for mobile. Maybe something like:

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  a.item {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

Change the value `400px` of your resolution. If its doesn't work because CSS style is overrite by another.. change `padding-left` and `padding-right` for:

```
padding-left: 0 !important;
padding-right: 0 !important;
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sLk0jf4L/46/)